# Strange behavior during access to private attribute

Tags: php, design-patterns

I wrote next singleton.

```
class Singleton {
    // object instance
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {}

    private function __clone() {}
    private $val = 'he';

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new Singleton();
            self::$instance->val .= 'llo';
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function doAction() {
       echo $this->val;
    }
}
Singleton::getInstance()->doAction();
```

When I get instance of it I add 'llo' to private attribute val. And see 'hello' instead of 'he', why I can access to the private method?

Comment: You are asking why it is permitted to modify the private property `$instance->val` from the static `getInstance()`?

Comment: where you can access "private method" if you haven`t private methods?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, yes

Comment: Because it's being accessed from within itself, not externally, so it is allowed to modify it. try `Singleton::getInstance()->val .= 'llo';` and you'd see the error I'd imagine you're expecting to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to private scope if for the whole class. It is not limited by private/protected/public methods. So you can access any private member from within the class but not from outside the class.

- **private** scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in its own class only.
- **protected** scope when you want to make your variable/function visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.
- **public** scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere, other classes and instances of the object.

You can read detail from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

```
class Singleton {
  // object instance
  private static $instance;

  private function __construct() {}

  private function __clone() {}
  private $val = 'he';

  public static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance === null) {
        self::$instance = new Singleton();
        self::$instance->val .= 'llo'; // Inside the same class you can access private variable
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function doAction() {
   echo $this->val;
  }
}
Singleton::getInstance()->doAction();
echo Singleton::getInstance()->val; // can't access
```